# Handling VirtualKey in Windows 8 Store Apps with C#

Tags: windows-8, windows-store-apps

I'm aware of how to handle key events, i.e.

```
private void Page_KeyUp(object sender, KeyRoutedEventArgs e)
{
  switch (e.Key)
  {
    case Windows.System.VirtualKey.Enter:
      // handler for enter key
      break;

    case Windows.System.VirtualKey.A:
      // handler for A key
      break;

    default:
      break;
  }
}
```

But what if I need to discern between lower-case 'a' and upper-case 'A'?  Also, what if I want to handle keys like the percent sign '%'?

Answer (score 8):

Got an answer elsewhere.  For those that are interested...

```
public Foo()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    Window.Current.CoreWindow.CharacterReceived += KeyPress;
}

void KeyPress(CoreWindow sender, CharacterReceivedEventArgs args)
{
    args.Handled = true;
    Debug.WriteLine("KeyPress " + Convert.ToChar(args.KeyCode));
    return;
}
```

Even better, move the `Window.Current.CoreWindow.CharacterReceived += KeyPress;` into a GotFocus event handler, and add `Window.Current.CoreWindow.CharacterReceived -= KeyPress;` into a LostFocus event handler.

Comment: Man, Your answer was the only and I mean only helping documentation i could find on the net regarding the CharacterReceived event. So it guided me in answering my own question here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24612653/windows-phone-8-1-shift-key-state-abnormal-behaviour   Thank you so much

Comment: So glad it helped you out!!

Comment: Thank you! It also helped me to answer my own question :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25475739/activate-a-textbox-automatically-when-user-starts-typing

Comment: Just another thank you. I spent an unholy amount of time looking for the right way to do this!

Answer (score 1):

You can't easily get this information from `KeyUp` because `KeyUp` only knows which keys are being pressed, not which letters are being typed. You could check for the shift key being down and you could also try to track caps lock yourself. Better you use `TextChanged` event.

Comment: Thanks Xyroid.  I'm trying to handle a condition where keystrokes are evaluated one at a time and code is called based on the first key that is pressed.  Unfortunately TextChanged won't work because the keystrokes don't come in all at once.

Comment: You're going to be in for a big surprise when somebody tries to use a Japanese keyboard. Converting keys to characters is very hard. Let the input manager handle it.