# windows phone 8.1 textbox character virtualKey validation

Tags: c#, keyboard, winrt-xaml, windows-phone-8.1

im develeoping windows phone 8.1 app.
In a textbox I want to prevent the user from inputting any non-digital letter only [0-9].

So here is my code:

```
 private void NumKeyDown(object sender, KeyRoutedEventArgs e)
        {

           bool isNumber = (e.Key == Windows.System.VirtualKey.Number0 ||
                 e.Key == VirtualKey.Number1 ||
                 e.Key == VirtualKey.Number2 ||
                 e.Key == VirtualKey.Number3 ||
                 e.Key == VirtualKey.Number4 ||
                 e.Key == VirtualKey.Number5 ||
                 e.Key == VirtualKey.Number6 ||
                 e.Key == VirtualKey.Number7 ||
                 e.Key == VirtualKey.Number8 ||
                 e.Key == VirtualKey.Number9 ||
                 e.Key == VirtualKey.Back);

            CoreVirtualKeyStates shiftState = Window.Current.CoreWindow.GetKeyState(VirtualKey.Shift);


            bool shiftIsNotDown = true;
            if ((shiftState & CoreVirtualKeyStates.Down) == CoreVirtualKeyStates.Down)
                shiftIsNotDown = false;

            e.Handled = !(isNumber && shiftIsNotDown);

        }
```

it works but there are two major flaws :

1- it also accept the shifted-characters( i.e !@#$%^&*) while that is not wanted.

2- when I start the app the textbox is filled with a number. I can input any number or characters(!@#$%^), also I can delete using the `BACKSPACE`. during this time the `ShiftState` is `NONE`. However once I delete all content in the textbox using the `BACKSPACE` the `ShiftState` changes to [ `locked | Down` ] and I become unable to input anything in that text box.

notice that i never touch the shift button !

where am I wrong here??

**UPDATE**

I discovered that using the swipe feature will input texts letters without triggering the keyDown event I was applying :(

any help is appreciated

Comment: Have you tried to limit the input by setting `InputScope="Number"` (in xaml TextBox)? Or you insist on full keyboard?

Comment: "The input scope does not perform any validation, and does not prevent the user from providing any input through a hardware keyboard or other input device."

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.textbox.inputscope

Comment: Wrong event.  Use CoreWindow.CharacterReceived instead.

Comment: @HansPassant I like those people who can put you on the correct track with one or two words. Your comment helped me allot in finding a solution that is not 100% satisfying but it works. please have a look on my answer.. regards :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok, I will try to answer this question based on the responses I received here and based on the research I did for the last couple of days. answer will be two sections [ Side Notes - solution ]

You may jump to (Solution section )if you are not interested in the details of the problems i found interesting to share with readers

**Side Notes:**

I have noticed the following problems

1. the most important is that window 8.1 and xaml and winRT
   documentation is extremely poor, and almost useless. I hope someone
   from Microsoft winRT team is reading this. Unless they are doing
   this on purpose to force most of the developers to go to C++.
2. regarding testing my application. I used 3 [[different]] input  methods. as the following picture :

[image: keyBoards]

and the result was different and incosistant with the KeyDown event as follow :

let me assume that I want to input the character (&)

- on Emulator keyboard : keyDown eventArg e.Key = Number7.
- on the PC touch keyboard : the KeyDown event will fire TWICE. in the
  first time the e.Key code will be shift, and in the second keyDown
  event the e.Key will be Number7
- on the physical keyboard ofcourse two keyDown events will fire bec.
  you have to press shift first then Number7 to get the (&).

also I noticed on the physical keyboard that regardless of which shift you press (i.e. right or left) the KeyDown event `e.Key` will show `LeftShift` !!

I don't know if this was special case to my computer keyboard , but  all these findings are to show that keyDown is not really trustable and documentation is lacking here

Also another finding I noticed that I couldn't control:

- wheneve you get the focus to an empty textbox the Shift button will
  get into the status of Locked ( to start you sentence with a capital
  letter). so any keyDown event will fire first the Shift key then the
  letter you pressed. this might confuse you if you were not aware
  about it .

I would like to thank @Bryan Stump, for taking me to the microsoft link [MSFT Forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/3c0f5251-9356-4f1d-a148-57024ae71724/testing-for-valid-numeric-and-currency-key-strokes?forum=winappswithcsharp)  that showed me important information to understand the situation:

> "Tracking KeyUp and KeyDown as Shiva's code suggests will work for
>   limited cases, but not all. For example, it won't work with ink or (I
>   think) IME input. It also makes assumptions about keyboard layout
>   which are not valid for all keyboards. Unless you can limit your
>   requirements to very specific, basic scenarios the only way to
>   successfully limit the input is to do so after the fact."  Rob Caplan
>   [MSFT]

This link assured me that the only avaiable way is to accept the character then remove it if not suiting your validation, hence the quote :"to do so after the fact".

and finally I would like to thank @Hans Passant for his short comment that put me on the right track:

> "Use CoreWindow.CharacterReceived instead".

after that I started to search and the only good example I found regarding the CoreWindow.CharacterReceived is on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16783820/handling-virtualkey-in-windows-8-store-apps-with-c-sharp)

and from there I started my solution as follow.

**Solution:**

Introduction:

- First: you can't intercept the character and prevent it from reaching
  the textbox.
- Second: you can't use the keyDown or keyUp events to know what is the
  character. you can only have an idea about the key pressed not the
  character resulted.
- Third: the event that will give you the character recieve is named
  "CoreWindow.CharacterReceived", but notice that you will know the
  character after it is written to the textbox. it is at this point you
  can choose to accept it or remove it
- Fourth: since the character is recieved in the textBox then the
  proper way to deal with it is the event textChanged.
- Fifth: and most important; is that the `CharacterReceived` event ***will
  fire in a loop on each letter in the word , and this needs special maneuver and validation***

so based on the Five facts above the pseudoCode will be:

rely on RegEx to validate the text and accept it; otherwise, if input was invalid then resume the previous state of the `textBox.Text`

```
string txtTemp = "";
    private void changedText(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {

    Regex regex = new Regex(@"^\d{1,4}$");


string txtToTest = txtNumber.Text;


    if (regex.IsMatch(txtToTest)|| txtNumber.Text=="")
    {
//do nothing 
    }
    else
    {
        txtNumber.Text = txtTemp;
        txtNumber.Select(txtNumber.Text.Length, 0);
    }

//Save the current value to resume it if the next input was invalid
    txtTemp = txtNumber.Text;
}
```

The above solution suited my case where i want to make sure that user will input numbers only. However there are cases that you want to make sure the user will input specific letter and you need to respond based on the letter pressed !! In such case you will need the following solution which is incomplete and lacking all possible scenario where the user might enter a letter from the clipboard (Paste ) or using the swype functionality of the keyboard.

Here the solution for the scenario where you need to control the input letter by letter (key by key):

1- since `CoreWindow.CharacterReceived` event is not specific to textBox ( it is window/page event). so you will wire it up whenever your textbox got focus. and unwire it whenever your textbox lose focus.

2- listen to the `keyDow event`. whenever it is fired, save the `textBox.Text` value to a temporary variable `txtTemp`.

3- set a boolean indicating that the character recieved is accepted or not (`bool acceptChange = true`) . and using the CoreWindow.CharacterReceived event set this boolean to true or false (accepted / not accepted)

4- in the textChange event if the bool acceptChange is true, then do nothing. If the bool acceptChange is false then reset the textBox.Text value to the temporary value you saved during the keyDown event ( txtBox.Text = txtTemp )

with this solution we can make sure that we accept only the character we want, with only one tiny problem remaining as the following:

suppose you set up your validation rules to accept only numbers. and textBox.Text = "752".
if the user enter letter "v" the txtTemp will be "752" and the new value for txtBox.Text will be "752v" and on textChange event we will reset the value to the previous value (i.e "752"). this is done by the help of the keydown event.

but what if the user didn't type the letter "v" but he copied it from another place and used the paste function then the new value of txtBox.Text ="752v", but the txtTemp will be "75" because the keYDown even was not triggered to capture the latest txtBox value :(

it is here that the importance of textBox event "paste" shows up.

so step 5 in my pseudocode is:

5- in the `txtBox.paste` event make sure that you cancel this event by making `e.Handled=true;`

and now I come to the code :

```
//this is critical to wire up the "Window.Current.CoreWindow.CharacterReceived" event when 
//the textBox get focus and to unwire it when the textBox lose focus.
// notice that the whole page is listening not only the textBox

    private void txtBox_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Window.Current.CoreWindow.CharacterReceived += inputEntered;
    }

    private void txtBox_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Window.Current.CoreWindow.CharacterReceived -= inputEntered;
    }



// temporary variable for holding the latest textBox value before the textChange event is trigerred
    string txtTemp = "";

    private void txtBox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //whenever a key is pressed, capture the latest textBox value
        txtTemp= txtBox.Text;

    }

// this boolean is to be used by the textChanged event to decide to accept changes or not
    bool acceptChange = true;

// here we recieve the character and decide to accept it or not.
    private void inputEntered(CoreWindow sender, CharacterReceivedEventArgs args)
    {
    // reset the bool to true in case it was set to false in the last call
        acceptChange = true;

        Debug.WriteLine("KeyPress " + Convert.ToChar(args.KeyCode)+ "keyCode = "+ args.KeyCode.ToString());
        args.Handled = true;

    //in my case I needed only numeric value and the backSpace button 
        if ((args.KeyCode > 47 && args.KeyCode < 58) || args.KeyCode == 8)
        {
            //do nothing (i.e. acceptChange is still true)
        }
        else
        {
    //set acceptChange to false bec. character is not numeric nor backSpace
            acceptChange = false;
        }
    }



    private void txtBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
    //the code here is my validation where I want only 3 digits number with no decimal
        if (txtBox.Text.Length < 4)
        {
            if (acceptChange)
            {
        // do nothing
            }
            else
            {
                txtBox.Text = txtTemp;

        //this is to move the cursor to the end of the text in the textBox
                txtBox.Select(txtBox.Text.Length, 0);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            txtBox.Text = txtTemp;

        //this is to move the cursor to the end of the text in the textBox
            txtBox.Select(txtBox.Text.Length, 0);
        }


    }





// this is for the special case where the user input text using Paste function
    private void txtBox_Paste(object sender, TextControlPasteEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Handled=true;
    }
```

:)

Comment: This is a great example of a useful post on stack.

Comment: for anyone who is interested in further investigation and testing I posted a separate question about swype keyboard and answered myself lol after 4days of testing here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24713319/windows-phone-8-1-swype-keyboard-event-capture

Answer (score 1):

Here is a post about a similar topic from the MSDN forums. There appears to be no good way to prevent input, though you could handle it after the fact. The suggested guideline is to allow invalid input but don't do anything with invalid input. For example allow the user to enter a character but don't allow them to submit the form..I don't necessarily agree but if you have to prevent input the CoreWindow.AcceleratorKeyActivated happens 'too soon to tell what character it is.' In your case you're just looking for numbers so I think it should be fine.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/3c0f5251-9356-4f1d-a148-57024ae71724/testing-for-valid-numeric-and-currency-key-strokes?forum=winappswithcsharp

I ran your code and don't notice the Shift key state switches when the textbox is removed.

I also used the on-screen keyboard and did receive the KeyDown event.

Also, your code did not accept the shifted characters either !@#$%.

In Summary I could not reproduce any of the bugs reported in the post.

Subscribe to the CoreWindow.AcceleratorKeyActivated event. You can check the VirtualKey.
This event happens before TextBox.TextChanged so we use this to leverage the routed event framework by filtering which key presses the textbox will handle.

```
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        Window.Current.CoreWindow.Dispatcher.AcceleratorKeyActivated += Dispatcher_AcceleratorKeyActivated;
    }

    void Dispatcher_AcceleratorKeyActivated(CoreDispatcher sender, AcceleratorKeyEventArgs args)
    {
        if (MyTextBox.FocusState != FocusState.Unfocused)
        {
            if (args.VirtualKey == VirtualKey.Number0 ||
                args.VirtualKey == VirtualKey.Number1 ||
                args.VirtualKey == VirtualKey.Number2 ||
                args.VirtualKey == VirtualKey.Number3 ||
                args.VirtualKey == VirtualKey.Number4 ||
                args.VirtualKey == VirtualKey.Number5 ||
                args.VirtualKey == VirtualKey.Number6 ||
                args.VirtualKey == VirtualKey.Number7 ||
                args.VirtualKey == VirtualKey.Number8 ||
                args.VirtualKey == VirtualKey.Number9)
            {
                args.Handled = false;
            }
            else
            {
                args.Handled = true;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: strange that you couldn't reproduce the problem. :( i have been suffering for a few days bec. of the virtualKeys and keyDown event were misleading. Anyways, really thank you so much for trying to answer and for providing that extremely useful link in MSFT forums. it helped me allot. check out my answer and feel free to correct me :)