# Activate a textbox automatically when user starts typing

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-runtime, windows-8.1

I want to activate a textbox when users starts typing in my Windows 8.1 Store app.

I tried handling `KeyDown` event of `Page`, something like this code:

```
    private void pageRoot_KeyDown(object sender, KeyRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (SearchBox.FocusState == Windows.UI.Xaml.FocusState.Unfocused)
        {
            string pressedKey = e.Key.ToString();
            SearchBox.Text = pressedKey;
            SearchBox.Focus(Windows.UI.Xaml.FocusState.Keyboard);
        }
    }
```

But the problem is `e.Key.ToString()` always returns capital english character of the pressed key, while user might be typing in another language. For example, the Key `D` types `ی` in Persian keyboard, and user might want to type in Persian, but `e.Key.ToString()` will still return `D` instead of `ی`.

Also I tried making that textbox always focused (my page contains some gridviews and so on, and a textbox) and while this solution works on PCs, it makes the on-screen keyboard to always appear on tablets.

So, what should I do? Is there any way to get the exact typed character in `KeyDown` event?

Comment: You could simulate the key press on the control and let it do the appropriate logic alone.

Comment: @YoryeNathan Is it possible in Windows Store apps? If so, how?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Store Apps and the limitations. Look into SendKeys, SendInput and PostMessage to see if any of them is applicable.

Comment: @YoryeNathan Seems that these functions are not available in Store apps.

Comment: You could ignore the first keystroke and just focus the text box, so to search "hi", I would press "hhi" or " hi", whatever is more natural to me. Another option is to use the [KeysConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.keysconverter.aspx) class with the appropriate `CultureInfo`.

Comment: @YoryeNathan `KeysConverter` is a Windows Forms class, which is not available in WinRT :(

Comment: How troublesome, that framework...

Comment: See if something in this MSDN Forum thread helps  http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/d3cf722e-9b3f-4c39-8be2-ccf5a4a92d44/how-to-convert-a-virtualkey-to-a-char-for-nonus-keyboard-layouts?forum=winappswithcsharp

Comment: @MarkHall Thanks. It really helps. Can you post it as an answer? I like to upvote it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Mark Hall suggested, It seemed that [`CoreWindow.CharacterReceived`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.core.corewindow.characterreceived.aspx) event can help solving this issue.

So, I found the final answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16804615/942659).

This is the code from that link:

```
public Foo()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    Window.Current.CoreWindow.CharacterReceived += KeyPress;
}

void KeyPress(CoreWindow sender, CharacterReceivedEventArgs args)
{
    args.Handled = true;
    Debug.WriteLine("KeyPress " + Convert.ToChar(args.KeyCode));
    return;
}
```

But this event will fire anywhere independent of current active page. So I must remove that event when user navigates to another page, and add it again when user comes back.

---

Update: I also had to move the cursor of the textbox to the end of the text, so user can write naturally. Here's my final code:

```
private void KeyPress(Windows.UI.Core.CoreWindow sender, Windows.UI.Core.CharacterReceivedEventArgs args)
{
    if (SearchBox.FocusState == Windows.UI.Xaml.FocusState.Unfocused)
    {
        SearchBox.Text = Convert.ToChar(args.KeyCode).ToString();
        SearchBox.SelectionStart = SearchBox.Text.Length;
        SearchBox.SelectionLength = 0;
        SearchBox.Focus(FocusState.Programmatic);

    }
}

private void pageRoot_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Window.Current.CoreWindow.CharacterReceived += KeyPress;
}

private void pageRoot_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Window.Current.CoreWindow.CharacterReceived -= KeyPress;
}
```